# SNMP HOSTMIB.MIB not loading?

Tags: windows, monitoring, snmp

Forgive me if the answer is something glaringly obvious but I just can't seem to get access to any OIDs under the HOST branch in SNMP.

I've used an SNMP browser to inspect a few of my systems and none of them show a HOST branch under ISO.ORG.DOD.INTERNET.MGMT.MIB-2.

Any thoughts as to why? I'm looking to monitor a few computer's hardware resources via SNMP and unfortuantely all such OIDs live under the missing HOST branch,

Any thoughts?

Comment: what platforms are you using? is the snmpd agent installed and running?  is your community string set correctly?  what tools are you using to poll the SNMP data?

Comment: Completely windows based.

Im just using the default community string "public", surely it can't be that as I can access SNMP data no problem. It is just the host branch that doesn't seem to exist.

I'm using the #SNMP crossroad browser - http://sharpsnmplib.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=15118

Answer (score 1):

So there's two quick answers:

1. Try the mibs via OID numerically (if you can), snmpwalk *may* be your friend.
2. You might just need to compile the relevent MIBs, you'd have to see the software/OS documentation to do that.

Comment: I tried accessing via a direct OID e.g. 1.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.2 for memory size. It returned an error stating "Variable does not exist"

The Mib hostmib.mib is shipped with windows surely it is compiled?

Answer (score 1):

Eriedor,

1.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.2 is not a valid oid.  1.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.2.0 returns memory size.

Standing on what LapTop006 said, issuing a command at the command line like:

snmpwalk server_name >> collectedstats.txt

will give you a file containing exactly what snmp stats are available on your server.  You'll then be able to move on to troubleshoot your if your gui is broken or your snmp service is broken. You'll also see what *other* oids are available on your system - which are typically hidden within a gui.

I looked over the Crossroads product, and suggest you look for a different mib browser.

http://www.snmplink.org/snmpsoftware/forenduser/#6

has a bunch of freeware\open source mib browsers.  Although it has limitations (for instance, it is abandoned), I use getif, which is listed there.